# How to use a Core Foundation function to replace "GetScriptVariable"

Tags: cocoa, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, macos-carbon, core-foundation

Now, I need to port the codes to 64bit. However, some deprecated Carbon APIs do not support 64bit environment.

the following case, I want to know whether the script is a kind of double-byte script. (It can not work in 64bit)

```
if ((GetScriptVariable(smSystemScript, smScriptFlags) & smsfSingByte) == 0)
{  
    //......  
}
```

My question:
1. Whether the "Core Foundation" support the non-Unicode string.
2. How to reconstruct the code section above without Carbon.